# Automation unable to find element even though Appium inspector finds it while inspecting it manually

Tags: mobile, automation, appium

The locator is not included in the xml hierarchy of the UI. In fact, it is an independent attribute on top of the UI which is why we don't see any label in appium inspector.

To get rid of the problem, added the below desired capability and now I am able to get the locator through the Appium inspector.

"appium:settings[enableMultiWindows]": true

But when I am trying to run the script, it is unable to find the locator. Any idea how to resolve this?

**Error**

- Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page